# How to createabsoluteurl passing two parameters in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am newbie in Yii2. Please help me to achieve this. I want to know how to create absoluteurl in yii2. I have tried the code given below but I want something different.

```
echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['site/confirm', 'id' => $user->id,'code' => $user->token,'&']);
output is http://car-rental.demoinja.com/site/confirm/69?code=275a9253dfc81efa47be4fdf1fc6a927&1=%26
```

But I want the url like this

```
http://car-rental.demoinja.com/site/confirm/?id=69&code=275a9253dfc81efa47be4fdf1fc6a927
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to add '&' in `createAbsoluteUrl` function; so you need to use following function.

```
<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['site/confirm', 'id' => $user->id,'code' => $user->token]); ?>
```

Comment: Output is same

`http://car-rental.demoinja.com/site/confirm/72?code=afde716505a995ec5e5a50f78e2721b5`

Comment: check your `urlManager` configuration in `web.php`. and also check your url rule.